# How to call a function within a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm relatively new to Python programming so please forgive me for a noob question. I am trying to see if it is at all possible to call the operation methods (add, sub, mul, div).

The program is a simple calculator which takes a series of integers and operators and performs the calculation once "=" is pressed.

A few noted for clarity;

1. comb is a user generated list of numbers and operators as shown in the dictionary opsymbols.
2. the line beginning with comb[0] is a test, eventually I'll replace this with a more complete way of performing a calculation based on the comb length

The code I'm having trouble with is as follows:

```
def calculator():
    opsymbols = {'+':add, '-':sub, '*':mul, '/':div}
    for sym in opsymbols:
        if sym == comb[1]: 
            opsymbols[sym]
            print(sym) # check to see whether the IF logic works.
    a = comb[0] 
    print(a) # check to see if assignment of "a" works
    b = comb[2]
    print(b) # check to see if assignment of "b" works

def add():
    a = int()
    b = int()
    result = a + b
    print("result =" + str(result))

def sub():
    a = int()
    b = int()
    result = a - b
    print("result =" + str(result))

def mul():
    a = int()
    b = int()
    result = a * b
    print("result =" + str(result))

def div():
    a = int()
    b = int()
    result = a / b
    print("result =" + str(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that call?

```py
opsymbols[sym]()
```

You have also problem with shadowing variables. But still you are looking for the solution mentioned above. You need to call func in dictionary using key `sym` and function operator `()`.

Comment: I check to see which operator is contained in comb[1] by comparing it against the dictionary key. Dependant on the key, I want to call the relevant dictionary value as a function (if that makes sense??)

Comment: `opsymbols` is a dict with functions. To call it you are choosing it by `sym` and then by operator `()`

Comment: I meant here ```if sym == comb[1]: opsymbols[sym]()```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm being slow. It worked. Thank you so much for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a second dictionary with function pointers to each one of those functions. Alternatively, you can just run eval() and add the operation code in at runtime.

Method 1:

`op_dict = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mult, '/': div }  # dict with function pointers`

`op_dict[op]()  # call the function`

Method 2:

`return eval('{num1}{op}{num2}'.format(num1=num1, op=op, num2=num2))`

If you're only going to have these 4 operations and there's only 2 nums you're calculating, it might be easier to use Method 2 and have all of this done in the calculate function. It would look something like:

```
def calculate(input):
    for op in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        if op in input:
            num1 = input.rsplit(op)[0]
            num2 = input.rsplit(op)[-1]
            return eval('{num1}{op}{num2}'.format(num1=num1, op=op, num2=num2))
```

Even if you have multiple operations with multiple input numbers, you can just do a split at each operation delimiter, and run the list of those calculations through the calculate function recursively

Comment: I would suggest `num1, num2 = user_input.split(op)` and `return eval(f"{num1}{op}{num2}")` for compacity.